# How to resolve canonical issue of a website hosted in yahoo small business (Shared Hosting)

Tags: seo, redirects, canonical-url, shared-hosting, yahoo

I have a website `www.myapp.com` hosted in yahoo small business, which is shared hosting and I don't have access to .htaccess file to modify. I called up yahoo team regarding the issue But It cannot be done. (It can be achieved in yahoo stores).

Basically I want `myapp.com` and `www.myapp.com/index.php` must be redirected to  `/www.myapp.com` so, What is the workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of these :

**Option 1 :** In PHP you could check if the URI is `/index.php` using the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` variable([doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) before any output is done to the browser, and then redirect the page using HTTP headers like that `header('Location: http://myapp.com/');` ([doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

**Option 2 :** Using JavaScript to dynamically change the URL of the page, see [this questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page).

**Option 3 :** Desperately hack Yahoo's servers to upload an *.htaccess* file...

Good luck ^^'